# how to solve logical error in if conditions in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, if-statement

I have a very simple logic and I have written conditions on that, I find the logic perfectly fine but it is always giving false results.
I have three fields immediate limit, hold limit and LDC. So the condition is when immediate limit and hold one limit are numeric values sum of them should be less than LDC and individual values of each limits should also be less than LDC.(When the limit values are not numeric they return a negative no.)

Here's my code:

```
immediateLimitError: boolean = false;
hold1LimitError: boolean = false;
ldcLimitError: boolean = false;
sumOflimitVal: any;
changedLdc!: any;
changedImmediateLimit!: any;
changedHold1Limit!: any;

private instantiateValidation(row: any) {
        this.newHoldSchedule = this.formBuilder.group({
            immediatereleaseForm: [(row.hold1ReleaseAmt != null ? row.hold1ReleaseAmt : ' '), Validators.required],
            ldcForm: [(row.ldcAmt != null ? row.ldcAmt : ' ')],
            holdOneLimitForm: [(row.hold2ReleaseAmt != null ? row.hold2ReleaseAmt : ' '), Validators.required]
        });
        this.changedImmediateLimit = row.hold1ReleaseAmt;
        this.changedHold1Limit = row.hold2ReleaseAmt;
        this.changedLdc = row.ldcAmt;

        this.newHoldSchedule.get('immediatereleaseForm')!.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
            this.changedImmediateLimit = val;
            if(this.changedHold1Limit >= 0 || val >= 0 ){
                if((val + this.changedHold1Limit) > this.changedLdc || 
                    val > this.changedLdc || 
                    this.changedHold1Limit > this.changedLdc){
                        this.immediateLimitError = true;
                }
                else{
                    this.immediateLimitError = false;

                }
            }
          });
          this.newHoldSchedule.get('holdOneLimitForm')!.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
              this.changedHold1Limit = val;
              if(this.changedImmediateLimit >= 0 || val >= 0 ){
                if((val + this.changedImmediateLimit) > this.changedLdc || 
                    val > this.changedLdc || 
                    this.changedImmediateLimit > this.changedLdc){
                    this.hold1LimitError = true;
                }
                else{
                    this.hold1LimitError = false;
                }
              }
            });
            this.newHoldSchedule.get('ldcForm')!.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
                this.changedLdc = val;
              if(this.changedImmediateLimit >= 0 || this.changedHold1Limit >= 0 ){
                if(val < (this.changedImmediateLimit + this.changedHold1Limit) || 
                    this.changedHold1Limit > val || 
                    this.changedImmediateLimit > val){
                    this.ldcLimitError = true;
                }
                else{
                    this.ldcLimitError = false;
                }
              }
            });

}

if(this.immediateLimitError || this.hold1LimitError || this.ldcLimitError){
                    this.displayError('The sum of Immediate Release limit and Hold 1 Limit exceeds LDC');
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
```

This code works on some values and some values it is giving false results. I tried debugging and changing the conditions but it doesn't work how I want it to work. Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems all the values are assigned asynchronously and yet separately. So there is no way to be assure that other values are updated correctly before checking the condition.

Instead you could use RxJS `combineLatest` function to combine the observables and `startWith` operator to provide a seed value.

Try the following

```js
private instantiateValidation(row: any) {
  this.newHoldSchedule = this.formBuilder.group({
    immediatereleaseForm: [(row.hold1ReleaseAmt != null ? row.hold1ReleaseAmt : ' '), Validators.required],
    ldcForm: [(row.ldcAmt != null ? row.ldcAmt : ' ')],
    holdOneLimitForm: [(row.hold2ReleaseAmt != null ? row.hold2ReleaseAmt : ' '), Validators.required]
  });

  combineLatest(
    this.newHoldSchedule.get('immediatereleaseForm')!.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(row.hold1ReleaseAmt)),
    this.newHoldSchedule.get('holdOneLimitForm')!.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(row.hold2ReleaseAmt)),
    this.newHoldSchedule.get('ldcForm')!.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(row.ldcAmt))
  ).subscribe(
    ([changedImmediateLimit, changedHold1Limit, changedLdc]) => {
      if (
        (typeof changedImmediateLimit === "number" && typeof changedHold1Limit === "number") &&
        ((changedImmediateLimit + changedHold1Limit) < changedLdc) && 
        (changedImmediateLimit < changedLdc && changedHold1Limit < changedLdc)
      ) {
        // condition passed
      } else {
        // condition failed
        this.displayError('The sum of Immediate Release limit and Hold 1 Limit exceeds LDC');
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  );
}
```

The condition has been written based on your question. You could adjust it accd. to your requirements.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was looking for some merge option. it still haven't resolved my problem. but has definitely helped me to optimize the code